# Select penultimate element

Tags: css

I want to select the penultimate element with CSS. The code looks this way:

[image]

so I tried this:

```
.panel-default > [id^=heading]:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}
```

But with no luck. Any idea how to always select the last "panel-heading" element?

Comment: `.panel-default > nth-last-child(2) {   border-bottom: 5px solid blue;}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
.panel-default > *:nth-last-of-type(2) {
    border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
```

}